# saving image in a create/update view in django

Tags: python, django

In the model i have ImageField:

```
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='post_images')
```

The problem is when i am trying to add a picture in create/update view. It does not work. It looks like it is working, there is no erros,  but the image is not being saved. The only way I can do this is by django admin panel.

create view:

```
class PostCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/create.html'
    form_class = PostModelForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = self.request.user
        post.save()
        return super(PostCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:home')
```

urls:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

form:

```
class PostModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'title',
            'text',
            'image',
        )
```

settings:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media_root'
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved the problem.
My template was lacking

> enctype="multipart/form-data"

in the form